# how to write the pattern to express `don't contain` in R?

Tags: regex, r

I want to match characters that don't contain "hallo" in the front of a string.

```
>string <- c("halloman","hi","dancing","manhallomorning")
>grep("hallo",string,invert=TRUE)
[1] 2 3
grep("(?<!hallo)\\w+",string,perl=TRUE)  
[1] 1 2 3  4  #the result is 2 3  which do not contain "hallo" .
```

how to revise the pattern  to express **do not contain `hallo`**?

Comment: I updated the answer. Check it out. By the way, why don't you just use `invert=TRUE` ?

Comment: dear falsetru,`invert=TRUE` can only be used in R,`^((?!hallo).)*$` can be more widely used .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookahead. Specify `^` to match only at the beginning of the string.

```
> string <- c("halloman", "hi", "dancing")
> grep("^(?!hallo)", string, perl=TRUE)
[1] 2 3
```

---

**UPDATE** accoridng to the question edit.

```
> string <- c("halloman","hi","dancing","manhallomorning")
> grep("^((?!hallo).)*$", string, perl=TRUE)
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need negative lookahead for this. This will do the work:

```
> grep("^hallo",string,invert=TRUE)
[1] 2 3
```

i.e., the combination of

```
^ = at the beginning of the string,
invert=TRUE to return elements that do NOT match
```

is enough.

If you insist on using a negative lookahead, this works, too:

```
> grep("^(?!hallo)", string, perl=TRUE)
[1] 2 3
```

I used negative lookahead, not lookbehind, and used the ^ anchor again.